# Memory usage for scalable usermeta queries

Tags: users, performance, user-meta, memory, scale

### Problem

Some time ago I posted a question about the [**scalability of `wp_usermeta` architecture**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/86908/wordpress-usermeta-scaling-for-thousands-of-users): my concern, as my client's database of users is growing fast, is now the **memory usage** of querying the `wp_usermeta` table.

In my situation, I am managing a CRM with thousands of users, each of which with around 15 *meta fields*. As I am getting this informations out of the database, the memory usage is exponentially growing, as much that now the `96M` I set as a limit is not enough.

### Data I collected (testing, profiling)

I have tried **profiling** and **refactoring** my code, by narrowing down exactly what I have to do, and I indeed optimized my queries as much as I could, depending on the situations:

1. In most situations, I have to get the *metadata* associated to one user only. In this case, both running `get_user_meta` and `get_userdata` work fine.
2. In some situations, I have to get the *some metadata* (~5 fields) associated to *some users*: using `get_userdata` exhausts my memory after ~2000 users; using `get_user_meta` with no `$key` (hence getting all the user associated metadata) exhausts my memory after ~3500 users; getting only the `$keys` I need actually exhausts the memory after ~3000 users.
3. In a few situations, I have to get *some metadata* (~5 fields) associated to *all users*: this is where, obviously, I feel the problem the most.

I have tried several options: using the **Wordpress APIs** is apparently highly inefficient for this kind of situation, as I pointed out above. Examining the *saved queries* on `$wpdb->queries` also gives me a huge amount of unnecessary queries (I guess this is why getting all metas above is more efficient than getting a few metas).

It must be noted that, I also have to run a preliminary `get_users` to get the IDs to run the above mentioned functions on.

Since all those APIs also **cache** the results, I thought it might be a good idea to run my own DB queries, and indeed I save up loads of memory, using just around a total of `40M` for around ~6000 users (my total now) with this query:

```
$wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT user_id, meta_value
     FROM $wpdb->usermeta
     WHERE meta_key='a' OR meta_key='b' OR meta_key='c' OR meta_key='d'"
);
```

### Questions

1. Am I doing **something wrong** in the approach?
2. I have never worked with this amount of data, **what is the memory usage I should expect** for this kind of situation? (In order to understand my hosting needs)
3. Would I be better off making a **new database table**? (The only thing that came to my mind, but I didn't try yet).
4. If the custom DB query is a viable approach, how should I organize the data collected by that query in some WP_User-like object structure?

Comment: Are you sure that your costume query will return 6k users? what are you going to do with it?

Comment: It doesn't return 6k users, it returns around 24k rows of metadata associated with them. I need this data to display filterable lists of users and relationships between users.

Comment: I fail to understand. No GUI can display anything related to 6k users. In other words, why don't you do the filtering in the query itself?

Comment: It does with the use of a paginated, filterable and searchable dynamic table. The most common use case for this application is the following: the agency has a set of manager users. Each manager user has possibly thousand of customer users assigned. He has to be able to glance at them and at a bunch of important data and also filter and search through them.

Comment: If it is going to be displayed paginated then why don't you ajax paginated results?

Comment: Problem is that results are indeed paginated but the whole user list has to be filtrable, not just the currently showing page.

Comment: You should do the filtering on the server side. The browser will die if you will try to send it 40M worth of information.

Comment: Still, the problem remains: in order to do the filtering don't I have to run the query on users and usermeta?

Comment: yes but you can limit the query to say only users with meta_key ='a' AND meta_value = "b".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7711/discussion-between-sunyatasattva-and-mark-kaplun)

Answer (score 0):

Just to put here the suggestion that came up after discussing the requirement on chat.

Due to the complexity of user filtering/search required, the wordpress user data tables is not a very good place to store the user's attributes. Instead it will make more sense to have a CPT and related taxonomies to store the user attributes required for the GUI, while maintaining basic information in the wordpress user table for login/authentication purposes.